# Magento2 - Extend Magento Block class in custom module

Tags: magento2, extend, magento-core

Basically, I want to use some additional functionality in the layered navigation file `Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/view.phtml` file for that using `Objectmanager` my code works fine. (Also I don't want to use **preference** Or **helper**)

so,

I trying to extend the `Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation` file in my custom module Block file so I can use default function as well as my custom block functions.
I did as per Below,

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class Filter extends \Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList $filterList,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\AvailabilityFlagInterface $visibilityFlag,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $layerResolver, $filterList, $visibilityFlag, $data);
    }
```

**Phtml file override** in `catalog_category_view.xml`

```
<referenceContainer name="category.product.list.additional">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Filter" name="custom.filter.view" template="Vendor_Module::view.phtml"></block>
</referenceContainer>
```

but it throws error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterableAttributeListInterface in D:\xampp\htdocs\magento233\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php:50 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento233\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Catalog...') #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento233\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(160): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Catalog...') #2 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento233\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(246): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Catalog...', NULL, 'filterableAttri...', 'Magento\\Catalog...') #3 D:\xampp\htdocs\magento233\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime(' in D:\xampp\htdocs\magento233\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php on line 50
```

Is there anything I am missing or anywhere I am doing wrong ?

Comment: You need to override the block file and phtml file into the custom extension.

Comment: yes Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/view.phtml  and its block Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation

Comment: share the code how you overide that block file and phtml file.

Comment: kindly check updated question

Comment: how you override your block file?

Comment: its in the question already class Filter extends \Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation

Answer (score 5):

1. You need to override block like this one. create `di.xml` file at following location

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <preference for="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation" type="Vendor\Extension\Block\Filter" />
</config>
```

and create the `Filter.php` file like this one.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Block;

class Filter extends \Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation
{


}
```

2. Override phtml file using the layout. create `catalog_category_view.xml` at following location.

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontned\layout\

```
<referenceContainer name="category.product.list.additional">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Filter" name="custom.filter.view" template="Alliance_ProductListToolbar::view.phtml"></block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Yes (one Up vote), But Is there anything I can use except preference. I don't want to use preference or helper

Comment: That is the proper way, otherwise you can use plugin if your requirement is fullfill with that one. and if answer help you then mark as solution, so it help other in community.