# How to extend app/code/Smartwave/Megamenu/Block/Topmenu.php this file Function in Custom Module or in Child Theme?

Tags: magento2, module, blocks, topmenu, megamenu

I need to extend a function from this file app/code/Smartwave/Megamenu/Block/Topmenu.php.

By using a module or in child theme.

How can i achieve that to extend that file like how to modify that function.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This might help you  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/305670/magento2-extend-magento-block-class-in-custom-module

Comment: Thank you @Tanmay for sharing the link i have successfully extended that.