# Magento 2 : Call admin config values in phtml file

Tags: magento2.2

How can i call admin configuration values like enable,input field value in template file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get config value for specific store from admin area](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/193000/get-config-value-for-specific-store-from-admin-area)

Comment: @Msquare am new to this can explain clearly

Comment: Try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/84484/82670

Comment: do you have block file and helper file into your extension?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya am having core module that config values(enable,sitekey) i need to call in phtml file

Comment: do you working on any custom module or magento default one?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya default one

Comment: Then you first need to overide that phtml file into custom extension and then need to apply things over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to illustrate this is by examining what Magento does in its core code. We can use downloadable products for this example.

In Stores > Settings > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog, [you can set](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-download-options.html) **Default Link Title**:

[image: Downloadable Product Options]

This is Magento's default value to display a title for the downloadable links section. The question is how we can get this value from the admin panel into the frontend template.

**First**, the admin value is stored at a config path. There are multiple routes to discover the name of this path. We can examine XML configurations (this one is configured [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/7c6b6365a3c099509d6f6e6c306cb1821910aab0/app/code/Magento/Downloadable/etc/adminhtml/system.xml)). We can inspect the admin page in our browser for clues. We can search for it in the core_config_data table. In this case, we're lucky: [Magento's DevDocs tell us](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/prod/config-reference-most.html) the path is `catalog/downloadable/links_title`.

**Second**, the Block class that's bound to our template retrieves and returns the value at this path. Magento makes this easy. Any class that extends ultimately from [\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/7c6b6365a3c099509d6f6e6c306cb1821910aab0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php) has access to the \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $_scopeConfig property. This gives us access to values configured in admin.

Here's how it works in our core example. [\Magento\Downloadable\Model\Link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/7c6b6365a3c099509d6f6e6c306cb1821910aab0/app/code/Magento/Downloadable/Model/Link.php) stores the config path in a constant:

```
const XML_PATH_LINKS_TITLE = 'catalog/downloadable/links_title';
```

The [\Magento\Downloadable\Block\Catalog\Product\Links](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/7c6b6365a3c099509d6f6e6c306cb1821910aab0/app/code/Magento/Downloadable/Block/Catalog/Product/Links.php) Block class uses this constant in its getLinksTitle function to retrieve the configured value at that path using $_scopeConfig:

```
public function getLinksTitle()
{
    if ($this->getProduct()->getLinksTitle()) {
        return $this->getProduct()->getLinksTitle();
    }
    return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
        \Magento\Downloadable\Model\Link::XML_PATH_LINKS_TITLE,
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    );
}
```

And just like that, our Block class knows the admin value.

**Third**, the template that's bound to this Block class calls the appropriate function from the Block. In this example, [Magento/Downloadable/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/links.phtml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/7c6b6365a3c099509d6f6e6c306cb1821910aab0/app/code/Magento/Downloadable/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/links.phtml) calls the getLinksTitle function and displays the configured admin value in this way:

```
<label class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getLinksTitle()) ?></span></label>
```

That's really all there is to it. Find the path, build a function in your template Block that uses $_scopeConfig to retrieve and return the value at that path, and call that Block function in your template to display that value. You'll do this a lot in Magento, so getting comfortable with this process is fundamental to being a Magento developer. Good luck!

Comment: am using magento2.2 template file is there...need to overide block or use any existing block file

Comment: The mechanics are the same. You'll need to extend that block in order to add a function to retrieve the value you need, and then override the template to call the function.

Comment: my template file already override...how to add block in that plz explain

Comment: This answer (below) gives a good example of how to do this. You'll need to (1) create a custom block that extends whichever block is bound to the template, (2) add a function to your custom block that retrieves the value you need, and (3) add a `preference` for your custom block to di.xml. Here are some visual examples of how to do that: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/305713/76310